# Calling 3rd party api from vs2010 (4.0 framework) c# class

Tags: c#, api, visual-studio-2010

We have an old application that we need to update to handle a call to a web api, however I haven't been able to successfully connect to the api in my attempts so far.  I've worked with api's in newer versions of visual studio, however the newer techniques don't appear to be compatible with this older application.  Here's my details:

Developed using:  Visual Studio 2010

Framework version:  4.0

I've tried several attempts but haven't been able to connect.  Here's one example:

```
public MyObjects MyApiCall(Lookupfilters filters)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var Response = httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://apiUrl.com:443/api/NameOfTask/123");
        var Result = Response.Result;
```

However, Response.Result throws the following error:

** at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()**

And the value of my "Response" is the following:

**Response = Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"**

How can I connect to a web api in vs2010 .net 4.0 framework?

Thanks

Comment: use `var result = Response.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` then do a check `if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode) { var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }`

Comment: this is if you want to use sync, but I recommend using `async` .